# How can I get exact same log file name in Rsyslog v-8

Tags: linux, logging, syslog

Previously I was using Rsyslog v-7.14 and having the template:

```
 $template UDP-Logging, "/var/log/RemoteLogs/%HOSTNAME%/UDP-%PROGRAME%-%$now%.log"
if $fromhost-ip ! '127.0.0.1' then -?UDP-Logging
& stop
```

Now switching to Rsyslog-v8 and request is to generate exactly same log structure as in client machine like:

> /var/log/messages, /var/log/mysql/ etc.

but in the directory structure on server as:

> /var/log/RemoteLogs/hostname/messages, /var/log/RemoteLogs/hostname/.

How can I achieve it in rsyslog v8?

Any help will be appreciated.